# XML to Array in nodejs

Tags: arrays, xml, node.js

How do I parse whatever is inside 'value' tag from below XML to an array in nodejs ? I tried npm xpath/xmldom, XMLExtract then xml2json but without success yet.

```
<response status="success"><result>
  <resource-monitor>
    <data-processors>
      <dp0>
        <second>
          <cpu-load-average>
            <entry>
              <coreid>0</coreid>
              <value>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
              <coreid>1</coreid>
              <value>2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2</value>
            </entry>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [`cheerio`](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) like this:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var _ = require('lodash');

var $ = cheerio.load('<cpu-load-average>\
        <entry>\
          <coreid>0</coreid>\
          <value>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</value>\
        </entry>\
        <entry>\
          <coreid>1</coreid>\
          <value>2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2</value>\
        </entry>\
    </cpu-load-average>', 
    { xmlMode: true }
);

var values = _.map($('cpu-load-average').find('value'), function(item) {
    return $(item).text().split(',');
});

console.log(values);
```

Try it on [requirebin](http://requirebin.com/?gist=2a581c9a3ce294810582e2d210506445). If it is a big XML file cheerio should be faster than `xml2js`.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the xml to json using [xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) and then spliting the value of the `value` tag using [string split operation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) will produce an array of values.